# resize img in responsive site

Tags: html, css, image, resize

I need to set my image size of the images inside a certain div. I could set the size directly from html, but the site is responsive and I need some "special features".
I need that when the container div heigh is 350px it stops shrinking vertically, and it starts to crop horizontally.
I can't use background-image, and with min-height it doesn't resize properly...
I already tried this:

CSS

```
#rslides_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 350px;
}

.rsimgsize {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="rslides_container">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <img src="images/teste/cabeca.png" class="rsimgsize"  />
            <p class="caption">With the Flight Support Department, you can assure more than one service, that it will help you to save time.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/teste/cabeca2.png" class="rsimgsize"  />
            <p class="caption">With the Flight Support Department, you can assure more than one service, that it will help you to save time.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/teste/cabeca.png" class="rsimgsize" />
            <p class="caption">With the Flight Support Department, you can assure more than one service, that it will help you to save time.</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="images/teste/cabeca2.png" class="rsimgsize" />
            <p class="caption">With the Flight Support Department, you can assure more than one service, that it will help you to save time.</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean that when the image reaches his normal size it won't anymore?

Comment: @thommylue No. his normal size is 1500x450. I want that when the container reaches 350 height, the img stops resizing, but the container continues... i want the img height to fix at 300px (the container has a 50px bottom white line), the container height to fix at 350px, but the container width to continue shrinking with the page (the image size is now fixed, and with overflow)...

Comment: See my answer below:)

Answer (score 1):

I made a simpler version of your code here to display what I think you want.

The key thing here is setting the images to have a `max-width` of `100%`, and then change the size of the images' container.

You can then use media queries to change the container size which will automatically change the images' size.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYWKBo

```
#rslides_container {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 350px;
}

.bxslider{
  list-style: none;
}

.bxslider li{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
}

.bxslider li img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bxslider li{
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

The clip property lets you specify a rectangle to clip an absolutely positioned element. The rectangle is specified as four coordinates, all from the top-left corner of the element to be clipped.

If the image is going out of the parent element, just add relative to the parent element.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp